# How do I retrive 1st value of group Id from Json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have my data coming as below

```
[
  {
    "GroupID": 1,
    "Title": "Group Name"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": 3,
    "Title": "Group Name 1"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": 10,
    "Title": "group Name 10"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": 12,
    "Title": "Group Name 11"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": 13,
    "Title": "Group Name 12"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": 5,
    "Title": "Group Name 3"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": 6,
    "Title": "Group Name 4"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": 7,
    "Title": "Group Name 7"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": 8,
    "Title": "Group Name 8"
  },
  {
    "GroupID": 9,
    "Title": "Group name 9"
  }
]
```

from below code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Property/GetGroup',
        type: 'GET', // You can use GET
        data: '{}',
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            //$('#GroupDropdown').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>');                                
            //console.log(res);
            $.each($.parseJSON(data), function (key, item) {
                $('#GroupDropdown').append(
                    $("<option></option>")
                      .attr("value", item.GroupID)
                      .text(item.Title)
                      );
            });
            alert(data.item[0].GroupID);
            alert(GroupID);
            //$('#SubGroupDropdown').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>');
        },
        error: function (request) {
            console.log(request);
            // alert("Some error");
        }
    });
```

over there I am trying putting alert(data.item[0].GroupID);
                alert(GroupID); to get the 1st value of groupid as value 1.

How should I get it?

Comment: try `data[0].GroupID` .Because data is array not an object.And also you are calling the value out of the each function, so no need add `item`

Comment: @prasad it coming as undefined

Comment: see my answer . i was added with code . you need parse the json before calling

Comment: @prasad i had tried but still coming undefined . the data which I defined in my question is coming when i do alert(data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `data[0].GroupID` .Because data is an array not an object.And also you are calling the value out of the each function, so no need add item .And parse the json data with some variable.You could call object from the variable

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Property/GetGroup',
        type: 'GET', // You can use GET
        data: '{}',
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            //$('#GroupDropdown').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>');                                
            //console.log(res);
            var datas = $.parseJSON(data); //parsing json
            $.each(datas, function (key, item) {
                $('#GroupDropdown').append(
                    $("<option></option>")
                      .attr("value", item.GroupID)
                      .text(item.Title)
                      );
            });
            alert(datas[0].GroupID);

            //$('#SubGroupDropdown').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>');
        },
        error: function (request) {
            console.log(request);
            // alert("Some error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: It coming as undefined

Comment: check updated : `var datas = $.parseJSON(data); //parsing json` are you added with this line. Parse tha json with some variable.And call from that `datas[0].GroupID`

Comment: now working from on changing  alert(datas.GroupID); to
  alert(datas[0].GroupID);

Comment: try this below  `console.log(datas)`.You could see the correct array in console .Then try with `datas[0].GroupID`